# Hide divider when opening minimap

Tags: term

I would like disable

> divider-mode

when enabling minimap-mode.  How do I ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you mean `window-divider-mode`, as I can not find any other divider mode (the answer explains the general mechanism anyway).

You can achieve it by using a hook function as follows:

```lisp
(defun minimap-divider-hook-function ()
  (window-divider-mode (if minimap-mode -1 1)))

(add-hook 'minimap-mode-hook #'minimap-divider-hook-function)
```